# HTML5 video tag controls="false" - controls show on pause

Tags: html, video

I have a standard HTML5  tag and using controls="false" to hide the native browser controls. But these show up again when the video is paused using javascript. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `controls="false"`. If you do not want any browser controls, then you should remove the attribute entirely. Because `controls` is a boolean attribute. It does not require a `false` or `true` property. Just defining it will be enough to make it true.